# asp.net delete cookie

Tags: asp.net, authentication, cookies

I'm using a cookie containing an encrypted key to use for authentication. What i need is to delete this cookie on logout. As per msdn a cookie cannot be removed from a client's browser, so I tried to set expiry date `HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["CAuthCookie"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);`, however the cookie remains. Any other ideas?

Comment: Cookie times are UTC, so use DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1), and also update Response (not Request) cookie.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:(place this in your logout code)

```
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("CAuthCookie", "");
cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);
```